# SQL server transactions stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, transactions

I want to make some tests on how SQL Server manages transactions, in order to decide the best isolation level for my website. I need to set different isolation levels and send 200 concurrent transactions in order to see how many committed, how many dirty reads and so on...
How could this be done? The stored procedures could be implemented directly on database, or is it best to call stored procedures from java application. 
My website runs java.
If so, how can I generate 200 transactions?

thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are on a new enough edition of SQL, be sure to look at snapshot isolation.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SQLQueryStress](http://www.datamanipulation.net/sqlquerystress/) by Adam Machanic for this. You can easily enter SQL you want to run and the number of threads.

To my mind choosing correct isolation level should be based on requirements, not just stress test because for example using dirty reads can have other issues too in addition to reading non-committed data -- for example missing data completely or reading it multiple times.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. I also want to know how can I generate those threads (just for my knowledge). Maybe using Java Class called Thread?

Comment: @pufuletghindescu Unfortunately I don't know how to handle threads in java